# How do I use a while loop for 2 strings in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am trying to make a program that asks you for a currency that is stated. And I want to make a while loop that repeats enter a currency until a correct currency is inputed. However when I hit run it says error right where i entered the while loop

```
    #current currency == num1
    num1 = str(input("Exchangeable currencies: usd, eur, cad, inr, jpy, vnd, krw, btc. Enter 
    current currency"))

    #target currency == num2
    num2 = str(input("Enter target currency"))
    num1amount = int(input("Enter amount of money"))

    list ["usd", "eur", "cad", "inr", "jpy", "vnd", "krw", "btc"] 

    while num1 or num2 != from list:
        print "wrong currency: "
        #current currency == num1
        num1 = str(input("Exchangeable currencies: usd, eur, cad, inr, jpy, vnd, krw, btc. 
        Enter current currency"))

        #target currency == num2
        num2 = str(input("Enter target currency"))
        num1amount = int(input("Enter amount of money"))
    break
```

Comment: Please learn the basics of python and do your research before asking a question here. We are not a coding service

Comment: `while num1 or num2 != from list:` is incorrect python syntax. I suggest you first figure out how to do the while loop with one currency input. In general, try to break down any programming problem into simpler parts and solve each of those simple parts. Trying to solve the whole thing at once is like trying to eat an elephant in one swallow.

Comment: Additionally, perhaps research ways to not have to repeat already written code.

Comment: well im using this as my research, because websites and textbooks don't explain well

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code, but concerning the while loop, you probably want to do the following:

```
while ((num1 not in list) and (num2 not in list)):
```

Comment: ... and highly recommended *not* to use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the builtin.